# How to identify the button clicked from a dynamically generated table

Tags: android, user-interface

I am populating a table dynamically from a string array.Each row of the table also has a plus and minus button to increment/decrement the value of one column. These buttons are also dynamically created like in the code below. Here how can I detect the exact button upon clicking. i.e; if I click on the '+' button of the 2nd row, how can I get the id of the button clicked for further processing.

```
 plusButton= new Button(this);
 minusButton= new Button(this);
 createView(tr, tv1, names[i]);
 createView(tr, tv2, (String)(names[i+1]));
 minusButton.setId(i);
 minusButton.setText("-");
 minusButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 plusButton.setId(i);
 plusButton.setText("+");
 plusButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`
```

Comment: Attach an event handler and that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an `onClickListener` listener for each button. Use the id of the button from `view.getId()` method on your `onClick()` method to identify the button click.

You can add separate listeners for each button like here (assuming that the id you are setting for each button corresponds to a row)

```
minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
             // Do some operation for minus after getting v.getId() to get the current row
        }
    }
);
```

**Edit:**

I am assuming your code is like this. Correct me if there is a deviation.

```
Button minusButton = null;
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    minusButton = new Button(this);
    minusButton.setId(i);
    // set other stuff and add to layout
    minusButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Let your class implement the interface `View.OnClickListener` and implement the `onClick()` method.

```
public void onClick(View v){
    // the text could tell you if its a plus button or minus button
    // Button btn = (Button) v;
    // if(btn){ btn.getText();}
    // getId() should tell you the row number
    // v.getId()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But the id i am getting is only of the last button created. ie. If there are two rows then there will be 2 minus and plus buttons. The onClickListener is catching only the click upon the 2nd row. I put a breakpoint and only the click on the second row is getting caught

Answer (score 0):

You could do with tags: `minusButton.setTag("-")` and `plusButton.setTag("+")`.

In your clickListener just get it from your button with `view.getTag()`.

Then switch between your actions comparing the string tag.

**Edit:**
ID's "should" be unique. The setTag() method may help you if setId() doesn't work for you.

Comment: The problem is not with identifying plus or minus.Please read it once again. I cant get the id of the button clicked.The onClickListener is only listening for the last button created in the dynamically populated table.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Anyway, the setTag() method may help you if (I don't know why) setId() doesn't work for you. Also, ID's "should" be unique.