# How to add click events for dynamically added buttons

Tags: android, layout, onclicklistener

```
public class ShowActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{

    private LinearLayout llaouyBase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboardactivity);
        llaouyBase = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llaouyBase);
        Button t;

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            t= new Button(ShowActivity.this);
            t.setId(i);
            t.setOnClickListener(this);
            llaouyBase.addView(t, i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                v.getId(), 8000).show();
    }
}
```

This is my activity, In the layout i have a blank linear layout with orientation vertical.Im trying to add 5 buttons in which i could do successfully.How can i add click events to these buttons?While running this, im getting Resource Not found exception.

```
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:233)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:265)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at com.example.testapp.ShowActivity.onClick(ShowActivity.java:55)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4103)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17117)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-04 12:22:07.535: E/AndroidRuntime(20957):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I followed this link give below.What am i missing in this code?

[How to identify the button clicked from a dynamically generated table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658144/how-to-identify-the-button-clicked-from-a-dynamically-generated-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    v.getId(), 8000).show();
```

with

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    String.valueOf(v.getId()), 8000).show();
```

If you pass an int value as second parameter to `makeText` android will look for a String with that `id` inside `R.string`. If it does not exist your app will crash for `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:`

Comment: always quick. beat me to it.:)

Comment: :) I thinked the same thing

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem

```
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                v.getId(), 8000).show();
```

Change it to

```
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ""+v.getId(), 8000).show();
```

or

```
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            String.valueOf(v.getId()), 8000).show();
```

You are using the below

`public static Toast makeText (Context context, int resId, int duration)`

Make a standard toast that just contains a text view with the text from a resource.

**Parameters**

```
context The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.
resId   The resource id of the string resource to use. Can be formatted text.
duration    How long to display the message. Either LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG
```

if the resource can't be found Throws

**Resources.NotFoundException**

Its expecting a resource which is an int which does not exist. Hence the Exception.

You should use the below

`public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)`

The above method expects CharacterSequence so use `String.valueOf(v.getId())`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    v.getId(), 8000).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    v.getId().toString(), 8000).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29):

> public static Toast makeText (Context context, int resId, int
>   duration)
>
> Added in API level 1 Make a standard toast that just contains a text
>   view with the text from a resource.
>
> Parameters context    The context to use. Usually your Application or
>   Activity object. resId    The resource id of the string resource to use.
>   Can be formatted text. duration   How long to display the message.
>   Either **LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG** Throws if the resource can't be
>   found. Resources.NotFoundException     public static Toast makeText
>   (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
>
> Added in API level 1 Make a standard toast that just contains a text
>   view.
>
> Parameters context    The context to use. Usually your Application or
>   Activity object. text The text to show. Can be formatted text.
>   duration  How long to display the message. Either LENGTH_SHORT or
>   LENGTH_LONG

Change

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            v.getId(), 8000).show();
```

To

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            String.valueOf(v.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: and why does He get a ResNotFoundException?

Comment: You're right, it should be String in the second parameter. I'll edit it.